# Foreign key reference mismatched data type error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

The `ArtistID` column in `Piece` table refers to the `ArtistID` in the `Artist` table. Likewise, the `LocationID` column in `Piece` refers to `LocationID` in the `GeographicLocation` table. However, both foreign key references throw a "not the same data type as referencing column" error. What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Artist
(
    ArtistID SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY  IDENTITY,
    LastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    FirstName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Nationality VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    BirthYear SMALLINT NOT NULL CHECK(BirthYear <= 1980),
    DeathYear SMALLINT NULL,
    Sex CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK(Sex = 'F' OR Sex = 'M')
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.Piece
(
    PieceID SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 5),
    ArtistID SMALLINT NOT NULL
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Artist(ArtistID),
    LocationID SMALLINT NOT NULL
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES GeographicLocation(LocationID),
    CommonName VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    YearProduced TINYINT NULL,
    Period VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    Medium VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
    Frame VARCHAR(35) NULL,
    AppraisedValue MONEY NOT NULL,
    AppraiserID SMALLINT NOT NULL
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Appraiser(AppraiserID)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.GeographicLocation
(
    LocationID SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Country VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    City VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Unreproducible.   When I run your code (and fix the order of the tables) the only error I get is `Foreign key 'FK__Piece__Appraiser__13F1F5EB' references invalid table 'Appraiser'.`   If you get the error you claim, it is from some part of the code that you aren't showing.

Comment: Same results as @TabAlleman. Also, a `smallint`, starting at 1 and incrementing by 5 only gives you 6553 potential `PieceID` values.

Comment: Side note: correct value for `sex` is `"yes please"`. For `"M"` and `"F"` use `Gender`.

Comment: And these days, 'gender' needs more than two possible values, and probably more than two characters, depending on who the audience for the data used by this scheme is.

Comment: @TabAlleman Sorry, throwing the error isn't what I meant. There are red squigglies and a pop-up stating "not the same data type as referencing column"  which I know now are warnings, not errors. However, you noted the order of the tables which fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @pmbAustin it's just a learning db.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed a table here, which is AppraiserID column in Piece table refers to the AppraiserID in the Appraisertable

So, when I execute your SQL I am getting below error:

Foreign key 'FK__Piece__Appraiser__322C6448' references invalid table 'Appraiser'.

First Create a table called Appraiser, then create Foreign key references for those column.

Below SQL I am able to create all tables and Foreign key references:

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Artist
    (ArtistID SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY  IDENTITY,
    LastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    FirstName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Nationality VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    BirthYear SMALLINT NOT NULL CHECK(BirthYear <= 1980),
    DeathYear SMALLINT NULL,
    Gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK(Gender = 'F' OR Gender = 'M'))

CREATE TABLE dbo.GeographicLocation
   (LocationID SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Country VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    City VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE dbo.Appraiser  
   (AppraiserID SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 5),
    AppraisedValue MONEY NOT NULL,
    AppraisedName VARCHAR(100) NULL)

CREATE TABLE dbo.Piece  
   (PieceID SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 5),
    ArtistID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    LocationID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    CommonName VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    YearProduced TINYINT NULL,
    Period VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    Medium VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
    Frame VARCHAR(35) NULL,
    AppraisedValue MONEY NOT NULL,
    AppraiserID SMALLINT NOT NULL)

ALTER TABLE dbo.Piece WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_Piece_ArtistID FOREIGN KEY(ArtistID)
REFERENCES dbo.Artist (ArtistID)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Piece CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_Piece_ArtistID
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Piece  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_Piece_AppraiserID FOREIGN KEY(AppraiserID)
REFERENCES dbo.Appraiser (AppraiserID)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Piece CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_Piece_AppraiserID
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Piece  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_Piece_LocationID FOREIGN KEY(LocationID)
REFERENCES dbo.GeographicLocation (LocationID)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Piece CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_Piece_LocationID
GO
```

Comment: That was it, thanks. This isn't production so I didn't need to alter tables, just made the changes.